# Getting data from form into Django not working

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to write a simple app that let users to login, in Django. I've downloaded a pretty bootstrap login template, but I can't hook it up to my Django project. When I click submit, nothing happens, Here's the view:

```
def login_view2(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    print("POST METHOD")
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print("FORM VALID")
        uname = form.cleaned_data['username']
        pword = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=uname, password=pword)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                print("The account has been disabled!")
        else:
            print("The username and password were incorrect!")
else:
    print("LOGIN FORM SHOWN")
    form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login2.html', {'form': form})
```

and here's the form

```html
<form id="login-form" action="login2/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="div-login-msg">
      <div id="icon-login-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
      <span id="text-login-msg">Type your username and password.</span>
    </div>
    <input id="login_username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" required>
    <input id="login_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div>
      <input type="submit">Login</input>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: No, that is not how you ask a question. You post the *relevant* parts of your code, in the question itself.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You're right, sorry. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given your HTML fields a `name` attribute, so the browser can't send any data to the server.

Also you need to display errors for when the form is not valid, using `{{ form.errors }}`.